# Searching through a Range with TextFinder is slower than searching the entire Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet with a lot of rows -- thousands. I want to search a specific column for text. I am using `Range.createTextFinder` but it times out. It even times out if the Sheet only has 4 rows of data.

```
// This is very slow
var found = sheet.getRange("A:A").createTextFinder("dog").matchCase(false).findNext();
```

If I search the entire sheet it is pretty fast but I want to only check a specific column.

```
// This works faster but it searches the entire sheet
var found = sheet.createTextFinder("dog").matchCase(false).findNext();
```

Is there a faster way to find the first row that has a string in a specific column?

**Update**: Here is the execution transcript:

```
[19-06-09 14:16:48:430 EDT] Starting execution
[19-06-09 14:16:48:513 EDT] SpreadsheetApp.openById([redacted]) [0.071 seconds]
[19-06-09 14:16:48:513 EDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Sheet2]) [0 seconds]
[19-06-09 14:16:48:514 EDT] Sheet.createTextFinder([b]) [0 seconds]
[19-06-09 14:16:48:514 EDT] TextFinder.matchCase([false]) [0 seconds]
[19-06-09 14:16:48:595 EDT] TextFinder.findNext() [0.08 seconds]
[19-06-09 14:16:48:596 EDT] Sheet.getRange([A:A]) [0 seconds]
[19-06-09 14:16:48:596 EDT] Range.createTextFinder([b]) [0 seconds]
[19-06-09 14:16:48:597 EDT] TextFinder.matchCase([false]) [0 seconds]
[19-06-09 14:17:21:064 EDT] TextFinder.findNext() [32.467 seconds]
[19-06-09 14:17:21:072 EDT] Execution failed: Service error: Spreadsheets (line 103, file "main") [32.626 seconds total runtime]
```

Comment: Show execution  transcript.

Comment: Before TextFinder was a thing, the way to do it would be to use `.getValues()` and use a for-loop to compare the values to your search string. That will of course work, but I'm wondering if your issue may caused by using `"A:A"` A1 notation. What happens if you use `getRange(1,1, sheet.getLastRow())`?

Comment: @TheMaster I added the execution transcript.

Comment: @Altigraph Yes, that seems to be faster. I created a test sheet with 8000 rows and did a search and it seemed to find quickly. You would think `TextFinder` would be smart enough to only search to the last row.

Comment: If searching the entire sheet runs quicker than searching the range, it probably *does* search only to the "last row"--`getLastRow()` on the sheet returns the last row *with content*, [`getLastRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getLastRow()) within a range returns the last row within that range.

Comment: I see. That is silly. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Range here is set to be the entire A column, including thousands of empty rows. TextFinder appears to search based on `getLastRow()` or something very much like it. For the sheet, `getLastRow()` returns the value of the last row *with content*, but on a range, it returns [the last row within that range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getLastRow()).

There are two ways to get around this: Specify a narrower range before creating your TextFinder

```
var found = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder("dog").matchCase(false).findNext();
```

Which will search only the first column, starting from the first row, and concluding at the last row with content.

Alternatively, you could use a loop rather than a TextFinder, e.g.

```
var column = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();
var foundIndex;
for (var i = 0; i < column.length; i++){
  if (column[i][0] === "dog") {
    foundIndex = i;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Will the second option take much longer or is TextFinder optimized for this kind of search/replace procedures?